# Display and Center Button Underneath Input Field

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm struggling with how to make my input field 100% width and centered and also have the "Add" button centered but displayed underneath the input field. I just need this part of the application to be responsive for mobile devices. I also plan to centre the other button when I get to that stage. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 965px) {
  body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.app {
  margin: 2.5%;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
} /* main div */

.header {
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
  text-align: centre;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
} /* title div */

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
} /* title */

.input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
} /* input tasks div */

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}



.input input,
.input-btn,
.item-text,
.action-btns,
.edit-input {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-btn {
  background-color: #23ba42;
  color: #F1F1F1;
} /* add button */

.todo-list {
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100%; 
} /* to-do list div */

.item {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
} /* individual tasks within to-do list */

.item-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
} /* task text */

.action-btns {
  text-align: center;
} /* task action buttons div */

.action-btn {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
} /* individual action buttons */

.remove-btn {
  background-color: #ce0a0a;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.edit-btn {
  background-color: #cb960d;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.update-btn {
  background-color: #23ba42;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.edit-input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
} /* hides input field for editing to-do tasks */
  
}
```

```html
<center><div class="input">
<input type="text" name="todo-input" id="todo-input" class="input-element" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
<br>
<button type="button" name="add-btn" id="add-btn" class="input-btn">
  Add
</button></div> </center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<center><div class="input">
<input type="text" name="todo-input" id="todo-input" class="input-element" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
<br>
<button type="button" name="add-btn" id="add-btn" class="input-btn">
  Add
</button></div> </center>
```

Aru u looking for this Try it And tell me if it Worked for u

Comment: That's part of the way there. I like how that's set up but I need to also have the "Add" button centered and displayed underneath the input field.

Comment: Its actually Displaying Underneath the Input field Just add tag <br>after completion of input field and it will Work!!

Comment: <br> is already in place within the suggested code. I know it is underneath the input field but I can't get it to centre. That's my main issue

Comment: Don’t use the [`<center>`element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), it’s been deprecated since HTML 4, back in 1997. Please, learn and *use* CSS.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See I am Getting Add Button in center Underneath the Input Tag

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Edge, I wonder if that's the problem

Comment: Yeah Check It Up and if it works Pls remeber to UpVote

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it on Microsoft Edge, Chrome and Firefox

Comment: can u send your Entire code what are you running now

Comment: I'm using the suggested html code that was sent by Rushabh and I'm using the css that is within my original post

Comment: can u share your output Image

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243897/discussion-between-rushabh-gandhi-and-nathan-bayne).